# to find the ration of lenght n wide in term of k

Tags: calculus

question----  A window consists of a rectangular piece of clear glass with a semicircular piece of colored glass on top. Suppose that the colored glass transmits only k times as much light per unit area as the clear glass (k is between 0 and 1). If the distance from top to bottom (across both the rectangle and the semicircle) is a ﬁxed distance H, ﬁnd (in terms of k) the ratio of vertical side to horizontal side of the rectangle for which the window lets through the most light.

my problem..
confused???  from where to start n how to find k values..

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  let the rectangular part be $L$ high and $W$ wide.  The height of the semicircle is $W/2$, so $L+W/2=H$  The light admitted is $LW$ plus $k$ times the area of the semicircle, so use the constraint to get the light admitted as a function of $W$.  Then differentiate, set to zero, ...